# ネイキッドドメインとゾーンAPEXの定義や違いについて教えてください

Tags: dns

下記リンク先によるとゾーンAPEXとネイキッドドメインは同じものであるかのように説明されています。

[Zone Apex 【ゾーンAPEX】 ネイキッドドメイン / naked domain - IT用語辞典 e-Words](https://e-words.jp/w/Zone_Apex.html)

> Zone Apex（ゾーンAPEX）とは、頭にサブドメインを伴わない、ドメイン名自体のこと。当該DNSゾーンの中で頂点（apex）にあたるドメイン名であるためこのように呼ばれる。
>
> 例えば、「example.jp」というドメイン名を登録して運用している場合に、DNSサーバの設定情報などの中で、この「example.jp」のことをZone Apexと呼ぶ。「www.example.jp」のようにサブドメインを伴うドメイン名と対比される。

ゾーンAPEXは上記のように説明されていますが、『当該DNSゾーンの中で頂点（apex）にあたるドメイン名であるためこのように呼ばれる』という部分に着目すると、`www.example.jp` を `example.jp` とは別のDNSゾーンで設定している場合は、`www.example.jp` もゾーンAPEXであると言えるように思います。(`www.example.jp` がそのゾーンの頂点なので)

この仮説が正しい場合、ゾーンAPEXが `www.example.jp` である場合はネイキッドドメインも `www.example.jp` になるのでしょうか？(ゾーンAPEXとネイキッドドメインは必ず同一である)
それとも、ネイキッドドメインは `example.jp` でしょうか？ (ゾーンAPEXとネイキッドドメインは異なる場合もある)

現在、ドメインやDNSが関連するプログラミングを行っており、プログラムや資料内で用語を正確に使用したいため、ご教授いただければ幸いです。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DNSでの"zone apex"と言う用語は[RFC8499](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8499)で明確に定義されています。対して、"naked domain"という言葉はRFCには見られず、[Wikitionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/naked_domain)に載っている程度で、公式な技術用語では無い俗語と思われます。ネット上の様々な記事を見てみましたが、ほとんどの場合で、"zone apex"と"naked domain"を同じ物(片方の別の呼び方がもう片方と言うこと)とみなしているようです。"naked domain"の正確な定義が無いため、断言は難しいですが、"zone apex"と"naked domain"は常に同じである、言い換えると"zone apex"と呼んでいるモノが"naked domain"と呼ばれることがあり、"naked domain"と呼ばれるモノが"zone apex"と呼ばれることがあるといってもいいと思います。

「用語を正確に使用したい」というのであれば、RFC8499に従い、"naked domain"という俗語は避け、"zone apex"または"apex"というRFCで定義された用語を使うべきでしょう。用語の和名としては、JPRSの[RFC8499日本語訳](https://jprs.jp/tech/material/rfc/RFC8499-ja.txt)に従って、「頂点」や「ゾーン頂点」という言葉を使うのがいいでしょう。